# Can't use cloud debugging to test my apk for Huawei

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I'm trying to test an apk with cloud debugging and I'm getting the following error when I tried to upload an apk:

[image]

I also added HMS plugin to my Android Studio but devices are not displayed in the device list when I opened one and it doesn't end or give any feedback(other than files are being pushed) when I drag an apk onto device.

Devices that I tried:

[image]

Comment: Could you plz provide your appid and what huawei devices are you using?

Comment: appId: 103612379, Mate 40 Pro

Comment: A network error is reported. It seems you are using proxy from your company or elsewhere. Please disconnect the proxy and retransmit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

The apk you uploaded does not have an icon. Plz check and add an icon for it and try again. This message will be modified later to make it clearer. :)
[image: apk]

---

It is a network error. Make sure that no proxy is used and your network is working. Then plz try to retransmit the apk.

Comment: no proxy, network is working but still having same issue.

Comment: @FigenGüngör Plz try to upload another apk using another device.

Comment: Updated my question with the devices that I tried. All of them gave me the same issue.

Comment: @FigenGüngör Could you plz send your apk to hmscore@huawei.com if it's convenient? We could reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FigenGüngör The apk you uploaded does not have the icon. Please add an icon and try again. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. =) I just created a hello world apk and was able to upload. Usually a flutter template comes with default icons but they are removed from example of huawei_ads sample project.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I have encountered the same issue in the past and that could be frustrating. One thing you have to know though, for Cloud debugging, the backend servers are on maintenance from time to time.  Please try to upload your APK again and see if your issue gets resolved by itself. If not, please let me know, I will see if more trouble shooting can be done.